# Do mixtures have a boiling point?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, boiling-point

Let's assume a mixture which can be heated without decomposing. [This site](http://www.ausetute.com.au/puresubs.html) explains that while pure substances have a sharply defined melting point and boiling point, mixtures tend to have a melting range. But what about the boiling point of mixtures? Is it always a point, always a range, or sometimes a point and something a range? If it is "sometimes", is one of the cases the rule and the other the exception, or are both pretty common?

To keep the question simple, we can stay with atmospheric pressure.

Comment: If there is a eutectic, then at that composition it is a single melting point. Quite often for some random mix of elements A and B it will be a range. The binary phase diagram will show what you need to know.

Comment: Assuming the components are miscible, a mixture has a distinct boiling point, which depends on the precise molar fraction of the solution. Look up *vapour-liquid diagram*.

Comment: See e.g. https://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/phaseeqia/nonideal.html

Comment: Mixture is a more general term. Solution can be of liquids or a liquid(s) and solid. Each case is different tough the relevant one is mentioned in the comment by Gert.